# Word wrap in phpInfo with css

Tags: php, html, css

Hello am trying to wrap text. In my CMS i add phpInfo() function and change css for that. 
Bur all looks good. When i come on Directive he looks like on screenshot:

[image]

**Css what i use:**

```
#phpinfo {border:none; background: #fff;font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;}

#phpinfo td, th, h1, h2 {font-weight: normal;}
#phpinfo pre {margin: 0px; font-family: monospace; }
#phpinfo a:link {color: #000099; text-decoration: none; background-color: #ffffff;}
#phpinfo a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
#phpinfo table {border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; border: none;background-color: #ffffff; }
#phpinfo .center {text-align: center; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;word-wrap:break-word;}
#phpinfo .center table { text-align: left; }
#phpinfo .center th { text-align: center !important; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;}
#phpinfo td, th { border: 1px solid #ddd; font-size: 100%;}
#phpinfo h1 {font-size: 20px;  padding: 20px 0 0 10px;}
#phpinfo h2 {font-size: 18px;}
#phpinfo .p {text-align: left;}
#phpinfo .e { font-weight: normal; padding: 3px; background: #ADD5ED; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;}
#phpinfo .h {color: #333; padding-top: 10px; background: #eee}
#phpinfo .v {background-color: #fff; color: #707070; padding: 3px;  word-wrap: break-word;}
#phpinfo .vr {background-color: #cccccc; text-align: right; color: #000000;}
#phpinfo img {float: left; border: 0px; padding: 5px;}
#phpinfo hr {width: 800px; background-color: #cccccc; border: 0px; height: 1px; color: #000000;}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
   ob_start();
   phpinfo();
   $pinfo = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   echo ( str_replace("module_Zend Optimizer", "module_Zend_Optimizer", preg_replace('%^.*<body>(.*)</body>.*$%ms', '$1', $pinfo)) );
 ?>
```

I use in word-wrap but dont work.

```
#phpinfo .v {background-color: #fff; color: #707070; padding: 3px;  word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Any solution?

Comment: Why are you trying to clean up phpinfo? that information should generally never be available to end-users.

Comment: I just change phpInfo() css style bcs is different from my design. The rest of the functionality of this feature is impossible to change.Check how joomla have phpInfo() style.

Comment: @Jony: You didn't understand what Marc is telling you. ***You should never ever display `phpinfo()` to end users. EVER***.

Comment: You guys i think dont understand me. I saw CMS. And that can see only Super Administrators. That is one module who showing System Information about cms, php, configuration data ect...

Answer (score 0):

As you did not mentioned how you linked the stylesheet and you said you were using a CMS, I think you have some conflicting stylesheets.

But the css property and value you are looking for is

```
white-space:normal;
```

which can be assigned to your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<style>td {word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 300px;}</style>
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```